Powershell - Use of $(get-item....)
I saw someone using the formulation:
function XYZ{ $(get-item....) }
I searched google for "$(get-item" and the only results were ignoring the "$("
Could someone explain the logic behind that formulation?
I searched google for "$(get-item" and the only results were ignoring the "$("
I tried it in ISE
but didnt even know how to retrieve it as a variable...

See Subexpression operator $( ). In the context of your question, there seem to be no reason to use it.

Tip for future syntax questions: Search for a textual description of the symbols you're seeing, eg. "dollar parentheses PowerShell" instead of "$( powershell"

This is use for subexpression. This will allow you to run a command or expression and return its result as part of a larger expression.

so its usecase in mostly for functions?

@MartinR, the Subexpression Operator is not only for functions. It is for expressions, which may include one or more functions. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.4#subexpression-operator--
